# How to train on very small data set?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, nlu

We are trying to understand the underlying model of Rasa - the forums there still didnt get us an answer - on two main questions:

- we understand that Rasa model is a transformer-based architecture. Was it
  pre-trained on any data set? (eg wikipedia, etc)
- then, if we
  understand correctly, the intent classification is a fine tuning task
  on top of that transformer. How come it works with such small
  training sets?

appreciate any insights!

thanks

Lior

Answer (score 1):

the transformer model is not pre-trained on any dataset. We use quite a shallow stack of transformer which is not as data hungry as deeper stacks of transformers used in large pre-trained language models.
Having said that, there isn't an exact number of data points that will be sufficient for training your assistant as it varies by the domain and your problem. Usually a good estimate is 30-40 examples per intent.

Comment: thanks! Wondered where can we see this model and if there's a paper explaining and showing benchmark results for this method. Definitely novel to me. Much appreciated!